# Cypress spy method on page component

Tags: vue.js, methods, nuxt.js, cypress, spy

What I'm trying to do here is simple : I have and filter method called "search()" that is called on different action on my page.

I'd like to "spy" this method and then check if it was called with : `cy.get('method').should('be.called')`

But really, I don't understand how  to reach the method, that is written in one of my component as vue method and spy on it. I've read the docs, but still can't understand how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created the [spy](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/spy#Method) before the method is called, perform the action to call the method, then check it is called?

Comment: Well I did write  cy.spy(object, 'method'), but what is this object before my method ? Why do I have to wrap m method inside this object, as documentation says ?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
mount(Component, opts)
cy.spy(Component.methods, 'method').as('method')
cy.get('@method').should('have.been.calledOnce')
```

Comment: I'm trying this approach in my react app in a functional component and didn't work. I think it will work only with classes